# Advanced Custom Fields If Statements with Select Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently building a website on Wordpress with ACF and am having troubles getting my If statement to work with my Select box.

I currently have a section where I will select a sport from the select box. Depending on which sport has been chosen I would like to display the Label from another select box named 'team'.

So in plain terms: If Sport chosen is equal to 'ncaaf' (value) then display the label of 'team'.

[NCAAF ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPS8G.png)
[Sport ACF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw9Nx.png)

Currently I am only getting the output 'No Team Selected'

ps. I understand that my code does not display the Label but I was just trying to get the if statement to work using the values

```html
<?php

    if (get_field('sport')) { 

        $selection = get_field('sport'); 

        if ($selection === 'nba') { 

            echo '<p>' . get_field('nba') . '</p>';

        } else if ($selection === 'ncaaf') { 
            echo '<p>' . get_field('ncaaf') . '</p>';

        } else {
            echo '<p>No Team Selected</p>'; 
        }
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: Try to inspect select in front end and check option values.

Comment: Hi HTML, The values are correct

Comment: Try to add second parameter like a `get_field('sport', $post_id);`